# Aggregate function within table I'm creating

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset where I have an ItemID and then quantity sold at each price like this:

```
ItemID  |  Quantity  |  Price
ABC        10           14.50
ABC        4            14.25
DEF        32           22.41
ABC        24           14.10
GHI        8            8.50
GHI        12           8.60
DEF        2            22.30
```

Every entry has a unique combination of ItemID and Price.  I would like to add a fourth column that has the total quantity sold for that ItemID.  So it would look like this for the above table:

```
ItemID  |  Quantity  |  Price  |  TotalQ
ABC        10           14.50     38
ABC        4            14.25     38
DEF        32           22.41     34
ABC        24           14.10     38
GHI        8            8.50      20
GHI        12           8.60      20
DEF        2            22.30     34
```

I can't seem to do this without performing an aggregate function on an aggregate function, which obviously gives an error.  How would I go about accomplishing this?

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: How do you know the TotalQ? You could write a function to calculate the TotalQ.

Comment: That sounds like it's exactly what I'm looking for.  I am very new to SQL so I don't really know how to write such a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    SUM(Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID) TotalQ
FROM 
    YourTable
```

Comment: Got the error:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
Column 'server.Quantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @weskpga - You probably need `SUM(SUM([Quantity])) OVER (PARTITION BY [ItemID]) AS TotalQ` if you are using this in the context of another query already grouping by `ItemID,Price`. It would be better to show us the original query rather than just the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
select a.ItemID,a.Quantity,a.Price,x.Total form table_name a
left outer join 
(select sum(Quantity) Total, ItemID from table_name group by ItemID)x
on x.ItemID = a.ItemID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this just in query you can write something like this:

```
;WITH CTE_Total AS
(
    SELECT ItemID, SUM(Quantity) as TotalQ
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY ItemID
)
SELECT t.*, c.TotalQ
FROM YourTable t
LEFT JOIN CTE_Total c on t.ItemID = c.ItemID
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3f04)**

But, if you want to  have automated computed column in your table, first you need to create function that does the calculation:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_YourTableTotalQ (@ItemID VARCHAR(3))
RETURNS Int
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @toRet INT

   SELECT @toRet = COALESCE(SUM(Quantity),0)
   FROM YourTable WHERE ItemID = @ItemID

   RETURN @toRet
END
```

... and then add your new column as computed using this function:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD TotalQ AS dbo.fn_YourTableTotalQ(ItemID)
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2b54/1)**